# Удаление файлов на сервере по маскам имен

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Подскажите, плз.

Нужно удалить файлы на сервере по маскам имён, которые будут браться из файла. Масок много, несколько десятков.

```
find ./www -maxdepth 2 -type f -name '*some*' -delete
```

Нужно примерно такое, только *some* берется из списка в файле

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прочитаем все маски из файла и повставляем разделителей в виде `-or`. Но предварительно на каждой строчке повставляем `-name`.

```
sed 's/^/-name /;2~1s//-or /' файл_масок.txt | \
  xargs -r find ./www -maxdepth 2 -type f  | xargs -r rm --
```

Comment: Что то ругается: find: paths must precede expression: mask1dsads-dsa.html
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

Comment: В mask.txt: mask1\*
\*mask2\*
\*mask3.html

Comment: Это из-за того, что вас в текущем каталоге есть файлы, подходящие под маску. Попробуйте исправленный вариант, там пришлось дважды обращаться к помощи утилиты **xargs**. Кстати, чтобы форматировать код в комментариях используйте символ \` (находится на клавише с буквой Ё).

Comment: Работает! Спасибо, выручили!)

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант, только что подсказали:

```
for line in `cat mask.txt`; do
    find ./www -maxdepth 2 -type f -name $line -delete;
done
```

Comment: У этого варианта, к сожалению, есть проблема: не будут удалены файлы из вложенных каталогов, если в текущем есть какие-либо подпадающие под маску. Пример: пусть есть файлы `./www/qwe` и `./qwerty` и маска `*qwe*`, то такая команда не удалит их.

Comment: Хм, понятно. Но мою задачу он выполняет, а больше и не требуется